# JavaFX - Multidimensional hashmap is overwritten

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, overwrite

I'am new here and don't kill me at start.
My code should creating student and count his grad average.
Everything is ok till I'am trying add another student.
Key from main Map is different but average from subjects from innerMap are overwritten.

If I'am creating few students, everyone from them have different name (main) but the same average (lastest which I added).

I'am creating HashMaps in this style:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Double>> mainMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>(); 
Map<String, Double> innerMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
```

and I created instance of my class with this map to get static acces:

```
private static AvgLists instance = new AvgLists();

public static mapClass getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

In another class I created method for add values in map:

```
innerMap.put(subject, grade);
 mainMap.put(key, innerMap);
```

Key for mainMap is String with name and surname of student.

Also, I apologize for my language. 
Thank for Your time!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code, but since both `Map`s seem to be fields, it's likely that you just use a single map for all students. You need to create new maps for every student though:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> mainMap = new HashMap<>();

void setGrade(String studentName, String courseName, double average) {
    // create new inner map, if there is none for this student
    Map<String, Double> innerMap = mainMap.computeIfAbsent(studentName, s -> new HashMap<>());

    // add grade to map for student
    innerMap.put(courseName, average);
}
```